# Show or dismiss a specific ViewController after performing an action

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to show a specific ViewController (or dismiss) a View after performing an IBAction in my iPhone App. I've tried

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

However this does not appear to do anything once the action has been performed.

A bit more information:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (selectedCell.tag == 1)
    {

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:@"Are you sure you want to delete this project?"
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Yes, I’m Sure" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];


    }

}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex])
    {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the project object that was swiped
        Project *projectToDelete = self.project;
        NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", projectToDelete.name);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:projectToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    }
}
```

I want the current view to disappear when a user presses the Yes button on the actionsheet.

Comment: Assuming self refers to the UIViewController that is currently displayed, why don't you use [self dismissModal...]. According to the docs the call is automatically forwarded to the presenting view controller. However, the presenting view controller would normally be self.parentViewController and not self.parentViewController.parentViewController unless you have some unusual view hierarchy there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to go all the way back to the first (or, root) view in my navigation stack.

All I need to do was use this method:

```
[controller.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Assume we are inside a UIViewController (or a subclass)

DestinationController *destinationController = [[DestinationController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:destinationController animated:YES];

...

// Assume we are now in destination controller

// Dismiss
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm getting an 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext' error when using this

Comment: @LordSnoutimus Ok that's a different story. It means that you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch managed objects using coredata (obviously to serve as a datasource for a UITableViewController), but you did not supply a fetch request and a context. [See more here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to show and dismiss a view controller is with pushViewController and popViewController.

To show a viewController:

-(void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated; 
// Uses a horizontal slide transition. Has no effect if the view controller is already in the stack.

And to dismiss:

-(UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated; // Returns the popped controller.

Comment: Although this is correct, these methods can only be called if using an  `UINavigationController`